# child DIV fiting with height of main DIVs (side by side)

Tags: javascript, css

How can I make my `.FormBox_Main` and `.ResultBox_Main` dynamically track the uncertain height that `.ResultBox_Child` can be. By default I settle a height of 100% to `.FormBox_Main` and `.ResultBox_Main`, but if the height `.ResultBox_Child` exceeds that 100%, it comes out fit of the "main" DIVs.

What can be done in the CSS (avoiding JavaScript) for the height to follow any height that `.ResultBox_Child` may have?

CSS:

```
div.FormBox_Main{
    background-color: #F1F1F1;
    width: 20%;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    border: 1px solid #0000FF;
}

div.FormBox_Child{
    background-color: transparent;
    width: 95%;
    margin-top: 10px;
    float: right;
    border: 0px solid #00FF00;
}

div.ResultBox_Main{
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    width: 80%;
    height: 100%;
    left: 20%;
    position: absolute;
    border: 1px solid #FF0000;
}

div.ResultBox_Child{
    background-color: transparent;
    margin-top: 10px;
    width: 98%;
    float: right;
    border: 1px solid #00FF00;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="FormBox_Main">
    <div class="FormBox_Child">
        <label for="SomeText">Some Text</label>
        <input type="text" name="SomeText">
        <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit">
    </div>
</div>


<div class="ResultBox_Main">
    <div class="ResultBox_Child">
        <ul>
            <li>Text</li>
            <li>Text</li>
            <li>Text</li>
            <li>Text</li>
            <li>Text</li>
            <!-- ++ Multiple Lines -->
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Current Result:

[image]

Comment: box-sizing:border-box;

Comment: sorry, doesn't work.

Comment: set `margin-top: 0px;`

Comment: don't work, fits out. I need that `.FormBox_Main` and `.ResultBox_Main` follow the height of the `.ResultBox_Child` when it's more than 100% height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a `overflow:scroll` to prevent this:

```css
div.ResultBox_Main{
    background-color: #333;
    width: 80%;
    height: 100px;
    left: 20%;
    position: absolute;
    border: 1px solid #FF0000;
    overflow:scroll;
}

div.ResultBox_Child{
    background-color: red;
    margin-top: 10px;
    width: 98%;
    float: right;
    border: 1px solid #00FF00;
    
}
```

```html
<div class="ResultBox_Main">
Result Main
    <div class="ResultBox_Child">
    Result Child
        <ul>
            <li>Text</li>
            <li>Text</li>
            <li>Text</li>
            <li>Text</li>
            <li>Text</li>
            <!-- ++ Multiple Lines -->
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It Works. Thanks. It's possible to prevent shows the default Scroll bars? Only appearing if necessary?

Comment: Yes, or you could hide them entirely. I'll let you look it up :-)